# Convert a 8bit list to a 32 bit integer array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, casting

what I have :

```
textdata = "this is my test data"
DataArray = [ord(c) for c in textdata]
```

now I want to transform this is into x 32 bit integer by combining 4 elements of the list together

Ex : DataArray[0:4] would become a 32 bit integer, and then iterate to the next 4 elements and do the same. In the end, I would have a 32-bit array with all my results in it.

How can I do this in python whitout iterating over the whole string. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Whenever you are using arrays in python, the answer is *always* "use numpy"

Comment: Do you have a preferred endianness?

Comment: Your `[.. for .. in ..]` also iterates over the whole string. But you can simply use [`struct unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) as it's, well, *made* to do this. Do note that the string length always must be a multiple of 4 (your example is, but I don't get the impression that was intentional).

Comment: No preference, as long as I am able to retrieve the original data with reverse process

Comment: Are you using 8bit data, or strings? they are different! Can you pl.ease specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.frombuffer(b'this is my test data', dtype=np.int32)
>>> a
array([1936287860,  544434464, 1948285293,  544502629, 1635017060], dtype=int32)
>>> a.tobytes()
b'this is my test data'
```

Use `'<i4'` or similar as dtype for endianness that's portable between machines.

I'm assuming that you can keep your initial data as `bytes` rather than `unicode`, because you really should try hard to do that.

Comment: this seems to works, but from a python begginer standpoint, how would I replace the b`string` with an actual string variable?

Comment: @AntoineLev You *can*, but you should probably guarantee that it stayed as `bytes` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your string is an integer multiple of 4, you can use NumPy in a very efficient way:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.fromstring(textdata, dtype='>u4')
# array([1952999795,  543781664, 1836654708, 1702065184, 1684108385])
```

`'>u4'` means 'big-endian unsigned 4-byte integer'.

**Edit**: If you use NumPy >= 1.14, then `np.fromstring` is deprecated, and the right way to process your text is by calling `np.frombuffer(textdata.encode(), dtype='>u4')`.

Comment: `fromstring` is deprecated since 1.14 for good reason ... OP probably shouldn't touch strings at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) built-in python module:

```
from struct import unpack

textdata = "this is my test data"
data = list(unpack('i'*(len(textdata)//4), textdata))
```

Result:

```
[1936287860, 544434464, 1948285293, 544502629, 1635017060]
```

You won't need to iterate over the string and you can find other [Format Characters](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#format-characters) if you want to use unsigned integers for example.

Comment: Unless you use Python-2.7, `'i'*(len(textdata)/4)` raises an error.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it with python 2.7. you can cast it to int to avoid the `TypeError`, I'll update it.

Comment: I could see it raising an error since `str * float` isn't defined.  `//` would "solve" it though (but it'd still be at the risk of truncating characters in `textdata`).

Comment: @abdelhalimresu That's what I said. It works in 2.7, but not in 3.x.

Comment: @jedwards I see.. but the data length must be a multiple of 4, otherwise the reverse operation will output a different string from the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following, which uses bit manipulation (big-endian):

```
def chunk2int(chunk):
    """ Converts a chunk (string) into an int, 8 bits per character """
    val = 0
    for c in chunk:
        val = (val << 8) | (ord(c) & 0xFF)
    return val

def int2chunk(val):
    """ Converts an int into a chunk, consuming 8 bits per character """
    rchunk = []
    while val:
        rchunk.append(val & 0xFF)
        val >>= 8

    return ''.join(chr(c) for c in reversed(rchunk))

textdata = "this is my test data"

chunks = [textdata[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(textdata), 4)]
print(chunks)

data = [chunk2int(c) for c in chunks]
print(data)

chunks = [int2chunk(d) for d in data]
print(chunks)
```

Produces:

```
['this', ' is ', 'my t', 'est ', 'data']
[1952999795, 543781664, 1836654708, 1702065184, 1684108385]
['this', ' is ', 'my t', 'est ', 'data']
```

If you're using characters with `1 <= ord(c) <= 255` in your input text, this will work.  If there are null bytes in your string, the `int2chunk` method may terminate early, in which case you'd have to pad the chunks.

There's also the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module, which may be worth looking into, and where you can change the endianness much more simply.